# Three JS: How to parse vertices of a plane in order to get an X and a Y coordinate?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

I have the following initialisation:

```
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 10, 10)
```

This creates a plane with 121 vertices and 200 faces. I'm trying to parse all those vertices in order to make a wavy surface, the formula for a wavy surface is:

```
( Math.sin( ( x + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) + ( Math.sin( ( y + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
```

where x and y represent the exact index of the point in the plane, think of it like a 2D plane:

```
------------
|    |     | <--- this square is located at (1,2)
|    |     |
------------
|    |     |
|    |     | <--- this square is located at (2, 2)
------------
```

Right now this is how I'm parsing the vertices in my update function:

```
function render() {
        time = clock.getElapsedTime() * 10;

        scene.traverse(function(node) {
            if(node instanceof THREE.Mesh && node.geometry.type === "PlaneGeometry") {
                for(var i = 0; i < node.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
                     DO SOME STUFF WITH THE VERTICES HERE
                }

                node.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            }
        });

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

I want to go through every vertex in particular, all while knowing its exact X and Y position in the plane, so I can apply that formula and create a wavy surface, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: alternatively if nobody has any idea, or it can't be done, I'd love a suggestion on how to achieve the constant wavy surface effect, there is an example on the Three JS website but it's done with particles using the exact idea I wrote down, I'm trying to simplify things although it really seems like I'm over complicating them.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is... the vertices themselves already have their own X and Y coordinates.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you are refering about the X, Y and Z coordinates of the vertices in the world, but those vertices are part of a plane, imagine you have an array of 4x4 elements, each element has a position relative to its array, for instance the first element is [1,1], that's the kind of X and Y I'm refering to

Comment: Ah I see you want to map indices to coordinates. In that case you need to do `index * [distance between adjacent points] - [total width of plane / 2]`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog total width is the size, or how many points are in a row? also how would you go about finding the distance between adjacent points?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog no offense taken if I was good at math I probably wouldn't be asking this :P thank you.